# Django Model '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, django, django-models, render.com

I have a Django script which runs fine locally, but on Render.com it fails with this error:

```
Sep 4 01:01:54 PM      create_tasks(limit=limit)
Sep 4 01:01:54 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/scripts/pull_from_outscraper.py", line 94, in create_tasks
Sep 4 01:01:54 PM      for task_object in task_objects[0:limit]:
Sep 4 01:01:54 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 422, in __getitem__
Sep 4 01:01:54 PM      or (k.stop is not None and k.stop < 0)
Sep 4 01:01:54 PM  TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Edit: this is the code from line 94 of pull_from_outscraper.py (the top line is 94):

```
for task_object in task_objects[:limit]:
        if not task_object:
            break
        if not outscraper_is_credits_left():
            break
        print(
            "Searching for", task_object.local_category.name,
            "in", task_object.google_location.city,
            task_object.google_location.country)
        # todo create keyword as part of models
        response = search_task_set(
            keyword=task_object.local_category.name,
            country=task_object.google_location.country,
            city=task_object.google_location.city
        )
        if response:
            task_object.task_id = response
            task_object.request_datetime = (
                timezone.now() +
                timedelta(seconds=240)
            )
            task_object.save()
            print("Task set")
```

Comment: I don't think this is the complete error description but seeing the issue, somewhere you are trying to compare an integer with a string. So, converting that string variable to integer `int(str_var)` will help.

Comment: you need to show us line 94 of pull_from_outscraper.py

Comment: @hiwa I've edited my question to include more of the code

Answer (score 0):

Whatever `limit` is, it's not an integer but a string, and you'll need an integer for slicing a queryset.

You can (try to) cast it at the time of use –

```
for task_object in task_objects[:limit]:
```

should be

```
for task_object in task_objects[:int(limit)]:
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that. `limit` should already be an int though, here's where it's defined:

```if 'SEARCH_LIMIT' in os.environ:
        limit = os.environ['SEARCH_LIMIT']
    else:
        limit = 2
```

Comment: Well, there to have it - if it's defined in the environment, it's going to be a string.

Comment: I would recommend just `limit = int(os.environ.get('SEARCH_LIMIT', 2))` for succinctness.